# systemd daily timer quits scheduling new events

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I've been using a systemd timer reliably for months, but recently got alerted that the triggered service job hadn't run. When I used `systemctl list-timers`, indeed I saw that no more triggering events were scheduled.

Thinking it was a fluke, I restarted the timer, used `list-timers` and saw that now the next run was scheduled as expected. But now the timer seems to firing only about once before it stops scheduling new events until the time is restarted.

Thinking this might be a systemd bug, I upgraded the host from `Ubuntu 18.04` to `Ubuntu 20.04` but the issue persists. **What can cause a systemd timer to stop scheduling new events?**.

I checked to see if the triggered service was hung and running more than 24 hours, but it's finishing reliably in about 8 hours.

Here's the timer unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Runs service
[Timer]
Unit=myservice.service
# Run every day at this time.
OnCalendar=*-*-* 10:00:00


[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Here's the `.service` file, which performs some maintenance tasks that take about 8 hours to complete:

```
[Unit]
Description=Do things

# Send email if this fails
OnFailure=status-email-devops@%n.service

[Service]
Environment="MAILTO=example@example.com"
User=example
Group=example
UMask=002
ExecStart=do-thing
ExecStartPost=/usr/local/bin/aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --region us-east-1 --namespace Example --dimensions Host=%H --metric-name example --value 1
StandardOutput=journal
```

This is with systemd v245.

Answer (score 2):

I found one possible cause: The service run by the timer had developed a bug which turned into an infinite loop. Since systemd timer's normally don't standard a second instance of a service if there's one already running, the timer appeared to have stopped scheduling new events.

One clue I got was comparing a stuck timer and a freshly started one. I used `systemctl show foo.timer` on the timer to get more detail about the state and saw this:

```
 SubState=running
```

The freshly started timer had instead `SubState=waiting`.

At that point I did what I should have done in the first place, which is to use `systemctl status` on the target service which of course showed that it was still running from last time, thus blocking the timer from firing again.

Comment: Yep, this will happen.  `*.timer` will not trigger a unit that is already running.  If your unit is a service, you could consider adding `RuntimeMaxSec=` to the service to stop it and set it to a failure state if it takes too long (i.e. longer than 23 hours).

Comment: @Stewart Great tip on RuntimeMaxSec= !

Comment: You solved a half year problem for me.